# Foreach on array with combined keys

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to loop through this array and echo results accordingly, my array displays like this at the moment:

```
Array (
    [2016 Q1] => 692.00
    [2016 Q2] =>
    Array (
        [0] => 809.00
        [1] => 1.00
    )
    [2016 Q3] =>
    Array (
        [0] => 290.00
        [1] => 8.00
        [2] => 2.50
    )
)
```

I need it to show something like this:

```
2016 Q1 
692.00
2016 Q2
809.00
1.00
2016 Q3
290.00
8.00
2.50
```

Although at the moment it shows like this:

```
2016 Q1
692.00
2016 Q2
Array
2016 Q3
Array
```

Here is my current script:

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($quarter_invoice, $quarter_ads, $quarter_account);

foreach ($result as $key => $value){
    echo $key.'<br>';
    echo $value.'<br>';
}
```

How do I access the second lot of Arrays to display?

Comment: you have child arrays. you'll have to detect/handle those, otherwise you'll just keep getting `Array` as your output, which is what happens when you use an array in a string context: the literal word `Array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first element is not an array, but a float/ single value. Your next two elements are both arrays. You need to have more consistency. I assume your first element should be in an array? like this ?

```
Array (
    [2016 Q1] => 
      Array (
        [0] => 692.00
    )
    [2016 Q2] =>
    Array (
        [0] => 809.00
        [1] => 1.00
    )
    [2016 Q3] =>
    Array (
        [0] => 290.00
        [1] => 8.00
        [2] => 2.50
    )
)
```

then your script can look like this

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($quarter_invoice, $quarter_ads, $quarter_account);

foreach ($result as $key => $value){
    echo $key."<br>";
    foreach($value as $element){
        echo $element."<br>;
    }
     echo "<br>";
}
```

if i am wrong, and you do need that exact structure you mention orginally. Do something like this

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($quarter_invoice, $quarter_ads, $quarter_account);

foreach ($result as $key => $value){
    echo $key."<br>";
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach($value as $element){
             echo $element."<br>;
         }
     }else{
       echo $value;
     }
     echo "<br>";
}
```

This may seem inefficient just for outputting (could just implode), but I assume you need to do more than just output when iterating and manipulating these different types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've marked it as correct as this is the one which helped me achieve my final goal. Appreciate you providing options too.

Comment: No problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just `implode()` them.  The `$value` may or may not be an array so force an array with `(array)`:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value){
    echo $key.'<br>';
    echo implode('<br>', (array)$value).'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this script does work as I said it needed it too so I have marked it up. Although the implode option isn't the best solution for my requirements. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks!  Next time post the _actual_ requirements.  This is probably best for just echoing.